# Make a HTTP request from ruby code on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku. I would like to perform a HTTP request (in a ruby script or in a controller of the app) using `Net::HTTP` but I get the following error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Net::HTTP
```

I assume `Net::HTTP` is not supported on Heroku, right?

Is there any other way to make a HTTP request from my app?

Comment: Do you have `require 'net/http'` in your code?

Comment: Actually...no... That works now. I feel quite stupide :) Thanks for the help. But it worked on my local environment without this require, I don't know why

Comment: Well, maybe you required it somewhere else and Heroku doesn't know about this point ;)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev please add your comment as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, for this type of error, it means that the gem wasn't required anywhere in project.
So just try to put `require 'net/http'` in your code.